# данные в массив сохраняются как объект (есть Angularjs)

Tags: массивы, angularjs, localstorage, scope, push

Есть функция:

```
$scope.addUser = function(){
    if ($scope.addName){
    $scope.users.push({
//localStorage.setItem("info", $scope.users);
        name:$scope.addName, 
        phone:$scope.addPhone, 
        message:$scope.addMessage
    });}
    else{alert("bad idea")}
    $scope.addName = '';
    $scope.addPhone = '';
    $scope.addMessage = '';
    }; 
};
```

Вызывается с кнопки и с инпутов добавляет данные в таблицу.
Нужно сохранить данные в localStorage, в комментариях моя неудачная попытка которая сохраняет в массив $scope.users данные в виде пустых объектов [object Object].
Как правильно сохранить ? Голову ломаю уже не первый день, на оф. сайте был, форумы шерстил, гугл просит пощады. В ангуляре как видно я новичок.

Comment: `JSON.stringify($scope.users)` - локалсторэдж только для стрингов

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но очень кратко и непонятно. То есть нужно преобразовывать тип к стрингу ? Но ведь js не строго типизированный язык, или к localStorage это не относится ? 
p.s. А после преобразования как жить ?

Comment: да, вы все верно поняли. и когда забираете из локалсторэджа парсите обратно в object - `$scope.users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("info"))`